# Select Query output in parallel streams

Tags: sql, database, oracle11gr2

I need to spool over 20 million records in a flat file. A direct select query would be time utilizing. I feel the need to generate the output in parallel based on portions of the data - i.e having 10 select queries over 10% of the data each in parallel. Then sort and merge on UNIX.

I can utilize rownum to do this, however this would be tedious, static and needs to be updated every time my rownum changes.

Is there a better alternative available?

Comment: did you read about the keyword SAMPLE (sampling?)

Comment: Why you're thinking that parallel querying same data over same network (or even locally) from the same server would be faster than single query?

Comment: My assumption is 10 queries spooling 10 records simultaneously would give me my flat file faster than 1 query spooling 100 records. Correct me here if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in SQL is well spread out over multiple spindles and not all on one disk, and the IO and network channels are not saturated currently, splitting into separate streams may reduce your elapsed time.  It may also introduce random access on one or more source hard drives which will cripple your throughput.  Reading in anything other than cluster sequence will induce disk contention.

The optimal scenario here would be for your source table to be partitioned, that each partition is on separate storage (or very well striped), and each reader process is aligned with a partition boundary.